# How to save a message with an image in a database

Tags: php, image

i'm busy on a forum right now, and i want to enable the visitors to also post messages with images and text via the forum. However, i don't know how to save this in the database and than read it as an image. Have you got any ideas?

Problem already fixed, i'm going to make an extra column called imgUrl (or something like that) and if this column has any value, i'll put img tags around the value.

Comment: You could store the image data as a blob in your database.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: @KristerAndersson he SHOULDN'T

Comment: @YourCommonSense - I didn't say he should, I just said he COULD!

Comment: @KristerAndersson and you *could* refrain from posting a BAD advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Add image upload to your website and save image's url to database.

Option 2: Use `base64_encode()` for converting image to text.

```
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['your_fileupload_name']['tmp_name']);
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $ext . ';base64,' . base64_encode($image);
```

Then you save `$base64` to your database, and you can convert it to image using `base64_decode()` when you are reading the database.

I prefer Option 1, because it's more efficent. Base64 encoding increases image size by 33%.

Comment: Thanks, i'll use option one.